# Trouble with returning multiple values based on one criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, array-formulas

I have a workbook. One sheet has a printable list of each driver and riders on the route while the second sheet has the table that has all the riders per trip.

*Sheet* 1 `MAIN` has a drop down for the `route number` in cell `A1`.

*Sheet 2* `Rider List` has the table of `trip number` in `A:A` and `rider` in `B:B`.

I would like the `riders` to auto populate in cells `A5:A30` and if overflow `A43` to `A68`.

So, for example the drop down is pulled to `route 14`,  I want all the `riders` for `route 14` to auto populate.

The table on `Rider List` is not static so using offsets to get the last value is what i was initially thinking once I got the code to work.

I would assume a **non-array** code would be better so if the drop down changes the array doesn't have to be reevaluated.

I have tried various methods.

```
=INDEX('Rider List'!$B$2:$B$1398, SMALL(INDEX(($A$1='Rider List'!$a$2:$a$1398)*(MATCH(ROW('Rider List'!$b$2:$b$1398), ROW('Rider List'!$b$2:$b$1398)))+($A$1<>'Rider List"!$a$2:$a$1398)*1048577, 0, 0), ROW(A5), COLUMN(A5))
```

Partial code here -

```
SMALL(IF(($A$1='Rider List'!$B$2:OFFSET('Rider List'!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA('Rider List'!$B$2:$B),1),ROW('Rider List'!$B$2:OFFSET('Rider List'!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA('Rider List'!$B$2:$B),1)-MIN(ROW('Rider List'!$B$2:OFFSET('Rider List'!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA('Rider List'!$B$2:$B),1))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))
```

Either gave errors or didn't work as i needed it to.

```
=INDEX('Rider List'!$B$2:$B$1398, SMALL(INDEX(($A$1='Rider List'!$a$2:$a$1398)*(MATCH(ROW('Rider List'!$b$2:$b$1398), ROW('Rider List'!$b$2:$b$1398)))+($A$1<>'Rider List"!$a$2:$a$1398)*1048577, 0, 0), ROW(A5), COLUMN(A5))
```

Either gave errors or didn't work as I needed it to.

Like I stated above I want the `riders` to dynamically change with each route selected in the drop down.

I'm not that great with excel so I'm sure I'm  close but not exactly where I need to be.

Comment: Okay I was able to get this formula to work. However i only want the name to appear once not duplicated by how often it appears in the schedule? This i have no idea how to do.

Comment: =IF(ROWS($A$5:A5)<=COUNTIF('Rider List'!$A$2:$A$1048576,$A$1),INDEX('Rider List'!$B$2:$B$1048576, SMALL(IF($A$1='Rider List'!$A$2:$A$1048576, ROW('Rider List'!$A$2:$A$1048576)-ROW($A$1)+1), ROWS($A$5:A5))),"")